# Materializecss tabs

Tags: css, materialize

I use [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/). I have two questions.
First: How to mark tab (as if was clicked) with "active" class? If I open tab (next after "active" tab), I don't see, that tab (among wrapped) open in this moment. (I use two rows of tabs)
Second: How to mark text of tab (as if was hovered, in two rows)
Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look in the documentation:
http://materializecss.com/tabs.html

You can use the callback-Function onShow
So when a Tab is shown you can do whatever you want ^^

Your Tab-Trigger (maybe your a-tag) gets the "active" class automatically, when activated

Answer (score 0):

to generate & nest tour tabs using materialize Css you can do something like :

```
<ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test-swipe-1">Test 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test-swipe-2">Test 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test-swipe-3">Test 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="test-swipe-1" class="col s12 blue">
Test 1 <!-- whatever inside first tab -->
<!-- you can nest another set of tab inside like so : -->
    <ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test-swipe-4">Test 4</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test-swipe-5">Test 5</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test-swipe-6">Test 6</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="test-swipe-4" class="col s12 blue">
        Test 4 <!-- whatever inside first tab -->        
    </div>
    <div id="test-swipe-5" class="col s12 red">
        Test 5 <!-- whatever inside secont tab -->
    </div>
    <div id="test-swipe-6" class="col s12 green">
        Test 6 <!-- whatever inside third tab -->
    </div>
</div>

<div id="test-swipe-2" class="col s12 red">
    Test 2 <!-- whatever inside secont tab -->
</div>

<div id="test-swipe-3" class="col s12 green">
    Test 3 <!-- whatever inside third tab -->
</div>
```

to change tab font color and background color on hover or active state you can put in your css :

```
 <style>
 /*when hover*/
.tabs .tab a:hover{
    background-color:/* put some background color*/;
    color:/* put some font color*/;
}
/*when active*/
.tabs .tab a.active{
    background-color:/* put some background color*/;
    color:/* put some font color*/;
}
</style>
```